# Careers: Remove only a tag

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, edits, jobs

I've just created my Stackoverflow Careers profile and CV.

I found a bug in edit tags area. Follow the steps bellow:

- The user clicks on the edit tags link
  [image]
- Then, he decides to remove [colobol](/questions/tagged/colobol) tag, the only tag in the Dislikes field.
  [image]
- When he clicks on the "x" of [cobol](/questions/tagged/cobol) tag, the tags from "Likes" are removed, too.

  [image]

Sure, they don't have to be removed. This must be fixed.

Comment: They aren't actually being removed, there's just a display issue where the overlayed field for the disliked tags is obscuring the liked tags.

Comment: Even this is only a display issue, it's an issue, and the issues are good to be fixed. :-)

Comment: Absolutely. The comment was just for informational purposes.

Comment: We're no longer auto-focusing on tag editors with content so the jerkiness should now be resolved.

Comment: I can't replicate it now, so it looks fixed.

Comment: @mythz, this is not resolved, yet. Why this is `status-completed`? I have the same problem.

Comment: Why don't you think it's resolved? We can now remove a tag without effecting the other tags from the other field? i.e. I'm not able to repro any undesired behavior.

Comment: @mythz, Watch this video record: http://www.screenr.com/zMf7 Isn't resolved...

Comment: @John Awesome, thx for the video showing exactly how to repro! will look into it at work tomorrow, tho as its the first day after big office move, we might have some moving problems. Will repro/fix as soon as I can.

Comment: Now it works good.