# Bug in editing tags on Careers profile page

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, jobs

The editing of Carrers profile is still buggy.

This bug is related to [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169935/careers-remove-only-a-tag).

- The user wants to edit his profile. He goes to his Careers profile and decides to edit tags pressing edit link.

[image]

- The edit camps appear:
  [image]
- The user decides to add a tag to *Dislikes*. So, he click on the text box, to focus it. When he does this the elements from *Likes* disappear. 
  [image]

After pressing *Save* button, the tags are saved correctly. This is only a display issue that has to be fixed.

Also, I make a [video record](http://www.screenr.com/Gzv7) that demonstrates this bug.

Comment: @downvoter, Why? Feel free to add a comment.

Comment: Voting works differently on meta, it's merely a "I agree" or a "I disagree". I'm picky on UI bugs, so I upvoted aka "I agree"

Comment: OS and Browser?

Comment: @JasonPunyon, Firefox (latest version) on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: @JasonPunyon It seems that it was solved. Please add `status-completed` tag.